# how to use the image search autohotkey function to wait for an image to appear on screen

Tags: autohotkey

i am new to autohotkey i know very little, i need to make a macro in the company where i work and i need to use autohotkey to make that macro.

What I am wanting to do is this. I need to access a JAVA application that stays on my computer, but this application takes some time to start sometimes it's fast sometimes it's slow I don't know exactly how long it can take to load.

What I need the script to do is wait for an image I captured to appear on screen when the application loads, while that image doesn't look like it waits until it appears on screen.

I researched a lot about autohotkey, and the imagesearch function, but I didn't quite understand how to use it

```
imagefound := false
time_loopStart := A_TickCount
timeout := 6000
sleep_after_each_imagesearch := 300
CoordMode, Pixel
Loop{
     ImageSearch x,y, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, C:\test\Javalogin.png
     if ErrorLevel = 0{
        imagefound := true
        break
  }
  if(A_TickCount - time_loopSart > timeout){
     break

  }
  sleep %sleep_after_each_imagesearch%
}
MsgBox, I found the picture
```

this script i found on the internet

I accept suggestions if the script needs to be redone etc.

I just need to make the script wait for the image to appear

if you have someone to help I leave my thanks :)

Comment: I'll spend more time with this in a bit, but right off the bat, there is a typo with `ErrorLevel` (you have "ErrorLebel"). Another typo in if-statement - "time_loopSart" should be "time_loopStart" I'm guessing.

Comment: yes, it was my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a similar script I'm using.

Basically, it looks for the picture and if it
finds it, it puts the coordinates where it found it in OutputVarX & OutputVarY.
If it doesn't find it, the values are 0.

```
Loop,
{
   ; first two store the found position, next 4 as the search area in pixels, then the file.
   ImageSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 0, 0, 600, 600, e:\play.bmp

   ; "0" means no match
   if (OutputVarX > 0) { 

       msgbox, %OutputVarX%, %OutputVarY%
       break

   }

   sleep, 200 
}
```

Some hints:

- Make a screenshot of your computer showing the image. Crop that to the size of the element and then save it uncompressed. Looking for the original png file may fail
  if it is rendered in some way.
- read the help on ImageSearch on how to allow the image to be a bit different.

Comment: Ouput variables being 0 means it's found at coordinate 0. They're empty if there is no match. Either check if they're empty or just use `ErrorLevel`. And they can be negative as well. And also coordinates being relative to what needs mention. Seems like to the default coordmode, which is now being used, isn't good to use in this case.

Answer (score -3):

@OP - I have an ImageSearch extension-wrapper that I designed and have been using for a couple years. It provides the wait that you are seeking as well as many other features that the native ImageSearch command is lacking. It's the backbone of most of the autohotkey utilities that I have been writing over the years. I am in the process of adding a couple additional features and have decided to post it (probably on GitHub) soon. If interested, let me know.

Here are the supported features

1. Supports user-defined wait-period (timeout in secs) to find image on screen, before halting search (with visible countdown)
2. Supports ability to search for multiple images at same time - in "OR" mode (AND mode in development now)
3. Can set unique search criteria for each image in search list
4. Supports verification of ImageFile path on disk prior to search, with notification (debugging assist)
5. Supports native ImageSearch Options
6. Abort support for long searches (especially helpful during debugging)

Comment: This isn't very helpful if you don't share your code.